# WebLogic 11g - possible to deploy jdbc driver as shared library?

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic11g

When configuring a data source on WebLogic 11g does anyone know if it's possible for the class specified as the connection pool driver to be deployed as a shared library rather than being installed in wlserver_10.3/server/lib?

The reason for wishing to do this is that we thought it might be more manageable to be able to deploy the driver in a complex production environment.

I've run some tests by deploying the jar file containing the driver with various deployment order values but always get "cannot load driver class" on server startup.

Thanks.

Comment: how do u deploy shared libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shared libraries from virtually anywhere keeping this major rule in mind, Weblogic must have permissions to read it.
If that criteria is met, please reference your jar in commEnv.sh "WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH" and restart the server and you should be good to go. This is handy for shared mounts with common libraries but always always always make sure you can read the file.